# Javascript not setting value for the first button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textbox whose value is set on the basis of is email id exists or not. Problem with it is it doesnot set the value when i click for the first time but on second click it sets the value. Problem is with email field in below code

```
 function CheckValidationSignup() {
        var Name = NameValidation();
        //var Email = EmailValidation();
        var password = passwordValidation();
        var cnfrmpwd = CnfrmPasswordValidation();
        var mbileno = MobileNoValidation();
        EmailValidation(); ***//This function doesnot set value and below line gives me value empty for first click and then it gives correct value on 2nd click***
        var Email = document.getElementById('EmailChk').value;
        var emailchk
        if (Email == 'valid') {
            emailchk = true;
        } else {
            emailchk = false;
        }

        if (Name && password && cnfrmpwd && mbileno && emailchk) {
            var VerificationCode = getRandomInt(1, 999999);
            var Name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
            var Email = document.getElementById('Email').value;
            var Password = document.getElementById('Password').value;
            var MobileNo = document.getElementById('MobileNo').value;
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("SaveNewUser", "Login")",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { name: Name, email: Email, password: Password, mobile_no: MobileNo,verification_code: VerificationCode},
                success: function (result) {
            $("#signup").hide();
                    $("#verificationcode").show();
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error Msg:" + result);
                }
            });
        }

    }

 function EmailValidation() {
        var Email = document.getElementById('Email').value;
        var div = document.getElementById('EmailValidation');
        if (!isValidEmailAddress(Email)) {
            div.innerHTML = '<font color="red" id="nameValidationFalse"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Please enter valid Email address</font>';
            document.getElementById("EmailChk").value = "invalid"
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("EmailIdExistsCheck", "Login")",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { email_id: Email},
                success: function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                        if (item.email_id_check == 0) {
                            div.innerHTML = '<font color="green" id="nameValidationFalse"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + Email + ' is Verified</font>';
                            document.getElementById("EmailChk").value = "valid"
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            div.innerHTML = '<font color="red" id="nameValidationFalse"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Email address already exists</font>';
                            document.getElementById("EmailChk").value = "invalid"
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error Msg:" + result);
                }
            });
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Html Code

```
<form action="#">
    <div>
        <input id="Name" type="text" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) CheckValidationSignup();"  placeholder="Name*" /> 
        <div id="nameValidation"></div>
        @*<font color="green" id="nameValidationTrue"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></font>
        <font color="red" id="nameValidationFalse"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></font>*@
    </div>

    <input id="Email" type="email" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) CheckValidationSignup();" placeholder="Email Address*" />
    <div id="EmailValidation"></div>
    <input id="EmailChk" type="text" style="display:none;"name="emailchk" />
    <input id="Password" type="password" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) CheckValidationSignup();" placeholder="Password*" />
    <div id="PasswordValidation"></div>

    <input id="CnfrmPassword" type="password" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) CheckValidationSignup();" placeholder="Confirm Password*" />
    <div id="ConfirmPasswordValidation"></div>

    <input id="MobileNo" type="tel" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) CheckValidationSignup();" placeholder="Mobile No*" />
    <div id="PhoneNoValidationValidation"></div>
    <div class="text-center"><a class="beta-btn primary" href="#" onclick="CheckValidationSignup()">Signup <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    <a class="beta-btn primary" href="#" onclick="ActivateAccount()">Enter Verification Code <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></div>
</form>
```

I have tried removing `<form>`

Comment: What does the console say? Have you even debuged it?

Comment: A fiddle would be nice.

Comment: Add html also in your OP

Comment: @Lee I have already debuged it and this is the output on first click `var Email = ""` means empty and when I click for second time it gives me what ever the result invalid or valid

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I have added code